# Type erasure and bridge method

Tags: java, generics, compiler-construction, bridge

Consider the following code:

```
List<Integer>ints= new ArrayList<Integer>();
lst.add(new Object());//no suitable method found for add(Object)...
```

Why this error is causing? On a compile time we have type erasure, and method `boolean add (E e)` after erasure will have signature `add(Object o)`. Can you write in detail how ompiler work in this case?

And what about bridge method? As i understood bridge metod have the following implements:

```
boolean add(Object o){return this.add((Integer) o)}
```

Comment: You are trying to add an Object to a list of Integers! Why do you expect this to work? That's exactly what generics were made for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How covariant method overriding is implemented using bridging Technique in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655541/how-covariant-method-overriding-is-implemented-using-bridging-technique-in-java)

Comment: where is `lst` defined?

Answer (score 7):

Type erasure occurs *after* the compiler has perform type-checking.  If it were the other way around, there would be no point in generics!

Comment: For what need a bridge method if we cant call him?

Comment: @St.Antario: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @St.Antario. Bridge method is generated by the compiler. So, you can't call them, because they don't exist until runtime.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth For what bridge method were added?

Comment: @St.Antario: It's explained here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html#bridgeMethods.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't evaluating

```
lst.add(new Object());
```

at runtime, you are evaluating it at compile time. At compile time, there is no method `List<Integer>#add(Object)`.

Answer (score 1):

Bridge methods go in class definition, not in methods, example:

```
public class Test implements Comparable<Test> {

    public int compareTo(Test o) {
        return ...;
    }
...
```

compiler will add a bridge method (invisible) here

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    return compareTo((Test)o);
}
```

because Comparable interface in bytecode has `int compareTo(Object o)` method and for JVM to detect that the class implements this method the class needs `int compareTo(Object o)`

Comment: It is `public int compareTo(Object o) {
    return compareTo((Test)o);
}` Otherwise it wasn’t a “bridge”. It makes a difference if a subclass of `Test` overrides `compareTo(Test o)`.

Comment: Consider the following code: `List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>(); ints.add(5):` What will be occur in this specific case if compiler doesnt generate a bridge method? Does bridge method generated after type-checked and before type erasure?

Comment: @St.Antario: **No**. Using a generic class will not create any bridge methods. So using an `ArrayList` creates no bridge methods. Look at the example above. It’s *implementing* a generic interface with bound type parameters. This is a situation where bridge methods are created. Completely different story than just instantiating a generic class.

Comment: @Holger Why no bridge method in my case? ArrayList<E> is subclass of AbstractList<E>. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html#bridgeMethods _When compiling a class or interface that extends a parameterized class or implements a parameterized interface, the compiler may need to create a synthetic method, called a bridge method, as part of the type erasure process._

Comment: *may* create bridge methods. Since `ArrayList` does not change the bounds of `AbstractList`’s type parameter `<E>` there is no need for bridge methods. The raw type’s methods still use `Object` where the generic type has `E`.