# Java reflection returning base type for Scala classes

Tags: scala, reflection, jvm, overriding

In the following code, the type of the `get` method of the Scala class as seen by Java reflection is `SSuperClass` (both in Scala 2.13 and Scala 3). Yet when doing the same with Java classes, the type is SubClass. Why is this? Can I get the more precise type using Java reflection?

```java
public class SuperClass {
    public SuperClass get() {return  this;}
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass{
    @Override
    public SubClass get() {return  this;}
}
```

```scala
class SSuperClass {
  def get = this
}

class SSubClass extends SSuperClass {
  override def get: SSubClass = this
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val getMethod = classOf[SubClass].getDeclaredMethods.find(_.getName == "get").get
    val returnType = getMethod.getReturnType
    println(returnType)

    val getMethodS = classOf[SSubClass].getDeclaredMethods.find(_.getName == "get").get
    val returnTypeS = getMethodS.getReturnType
    println(returnTypeS)
  }
}
```

I know this could be solved using Scala reflection, but that opens a new can of worms (e.g. needing separate solutions for Scala 2 and Scala 3).

Comment: If you want to return `this`, why not just use `this.type`?

Comment: This is just so that the example is short. The real case returns classes from a different hierarchy of classes than the one it is called on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print `classOf[SSubClass].getDeclaredMethods` you'll see that there are two methods

```
public App$SSuperClass App$SSubClass.get()
public App$SSubClass App$SSubClass.get()
```

Just `.find` finds the first one.

You can add `filter(!_.isBridge)` in

```scala
classOf[SSubClass].getDeclaredMethods.filter(!_.isBridge).find(_.getName == "get").get
```

[How bridge method works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348555/how-bridge-method-works)

[What Method.isBridge used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289731/what-method-isbridge-used-for)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the primary version of the method by using `getMethod`. If you do not know the parameter types, you can get them from the version you have found:

```scala
    val preciseMethod = classOf[SSubClass].getMethod(getMethodS.getName, getMethodS.getParameterTypes.toSeq:_*)
    val returnTypeP = preciseMethod.getReturnType
    println(returnTypeP)
```