# Why Java compiler creates bridge methods for methods without parameters (getter methods)

Tags: java, generics, overriding, bridge

I do understand the need to create bridge methods for example a setter method that expects an argument to be passed, but what about a getter method? Why does Java produce a bridge method as well?

Here is a dummy code produced by ChatGPT to make things more specific:

```
class Box<T> {
private T value;

public void setValue(T value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public T getValue() {
    return value;
}
}

class StringBox extends Box<String> {
public void setValue(String value) {
    System.out.println("Setting a String value in StringBox");
    super.setValue(value.toString());
}

public String getValue() {
    System.out.println("Getting String value from StringBox");
    return super.getValue();
}
}
```

The Box class after the erasure will have the following method:
`public Object getValue();`
In the StringBox class, we defined the method:
`public String getValue()`
But these two methods have the same signature and the return type of the overriding method uses String as return type, which is a subclass of Object class(Covariant Return Type)
So it seems that overriding is already complete. Why is there a need for the bridge method?
What am i missing?

Comment: Can you provide the decompiled class file to show there is a bridge method? I don't see how there can be, considering it would have the same signature.

Comment: I got the methods using reflection and used the isBridge method. Both set and get methods have a bridge. I followed this example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-class-isbridge-method-in-java/

Comment: I think there can be methods which differ only in return type in a class file: this is a difference between Java (which doesn't consider return type part of the signature) and the JVM (which does).  I don't want to commit to it as an answer, but [JVM 4.7.9.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.9.1) may well contain the answer.

Comment: @Andy yes, the return type is part of the method descriptor and by [JVM 4.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.6): "No two methods in one class file may have the same name and descriptor ([§4.3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.3))"

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18655541/6395627

Comment: None of the "duplicates" explain why a bridge method is necessary in this case. This question should not have been closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the JVM doesn't implement return type covariance. Even without generics, Java requires bridge methods to implement return type covariance on the JVM. If you compile the following,

```
class MySupplier {
    public Object supply() { return null; }
}
class HelloSupplier extends MySupplier {
    @Override public String supply() { return "Hello, World!"; }
}
```

you will find that `HelloSupplier` contains bytecode amounting to the following:

```
class HelloSupplier extends MySupplier {
    public String supply() { return "Hello, World!"; }
    public /*bridge*/ Object supply() { return this.supply()/*String*/; }
    // in bytecode, all method calls include the signature of the method, including the return type (which is written after the method name and parameters)
    // the bridge method supply()Object calls the method supply()String
    // note that bytecode allows overloading on return type, even though Java doesn't
}
```

If you look at the *JVM* definition of an override, you will notice that it differs from *Java*'s idea of an override, in that the signatures of overrides must match *exactly* in the eyes of the JVM. You don't get to relax the parameter types or strengthen the return type.

[JVM Specification SE 20, Section 5.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se20/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.5)

> An instance method `mC` can override another instance method `mA` iff all of the following are true:
>
> - `mC` has the same name and descriptor as `mA`.
> - ...

This is important, because this is how the JVM decides what method to call when you do a virtual lookup. A virtual call (`invokevirtual`) to `MySupplier#supply()Object` on a `HelloSupplier` object will never call `HelloSupplier#supply()String`, since a `supply()String` method does not override a `supply()Object` method in the eyes of the JVM (even though it does in Java). Such a virtual method call will call `HelloSupplier#supply()Object`, if it exists, or else look for such a method in superclasses. The Java compiler, in order to implement return type covariance, must override `MySupplier#supply()Object` in the only way the JVM understands: by defining `HelloSupplier#supply()Object`.

Because the JVM doesn't implement return type covariance anyway, the Java compiler can't leverage return type covariance to sometimes avoid emitting bridges for generic code.